# Spring boot server shutdown

Tags: spring, security, spring-boot, spring-security, shutdown

When running the Spring boot server it is running. Sometimes it is shut down automatically. I got the ERROR like this.

I have added the "spring-boot-starter-tomcat" in pom.xml also

--------------------Error----------

```
INFO  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2cdf8d8a: startup date [Fri Aug 17 12:45:04 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-17 23:04:22 INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

---

Comment: To effectively help you, we would need more info. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It sounds like there is not all the relevant logs in your post. What you are showing here is just spring logging its shutdown process (basically saying "Okay, now I will unregister JMX" and some more informations related to context closing). The real error if any is printed should appear above those lines you mentionned.

Comment: You can enable `logging.level.org.springframework.boot=DEBUG` and `logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG` flags to get more info on shutdown.